Can i use @if with <ng-content>?
According to Angular documentation
https://angular.dev/guide/components/content-projection

You should not conditionally include <ng-content> with ngIf, ngFor, or ngSwitch.

But what about @if, @for, @switch? Is it safe to conditionally include <ng-content> with those?
By the way, i know we can use <ng-template>, *ngTemplateOutlet, etc. That is not my question.

A "ng-content" is a "place" where you can add or not html tags (or angular components) if empty no render nothing, why is the reason to use under a @if?
